# Can "enemy" be used as a plural noun? (Not as a collective noun)

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, countable-nouns, collective-nouns, irregular-plurals

I’ve been recently told that *defeat five enemy* or *ten enemy are here*
is perfectly acceptable in English grammar.

Personally, I’m inclined to believe that only *five enemies* or *five
enemy units* are grammatically correct. (As well as the use of *enemy*
to describe enemies as a whole, like in *They are the enemy.*)

I’d like to know if *five enemy* **is** actually acceptable in English
grammar.

Comment: English is not a clearly defined language. There’s a lot of ambiguity, especially in the more advanced rules. Think of a rule, and I can probably find nearly as many exceptions to that rule as there are conformers! It may be confusing, but it also gives you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: While the word *enemy* can refer to a single person OR a group of people, my ear/brain recognizes it as singular.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking Good Luck.

Comment: I don't recognise this usage. I would say "ten of the enemy".

Comment: Note that "They are the enemy" is merely a circumvention of the problem. You could as correctly say "They are the singularity" because the subject is *they* not *enemy* or *singularity*.

Comment: Russia is our enemy.  China is our enemy.  Russia and China are our enemies.  The Democrats are my enemy.  The Republicans are my enemy.  The Democrats and Republicans are my enemies.  Fred is my enemy.  Joe is my enemy.  Fred and Joe are my enemies.

Comment: @Robusto Flee for the enemy are upon us!

Comment: @tchrist: Indeed they is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can* use ***enemy*** with a plural verb, but when you do so it is only ever as a collective or mass noun, never as a countable one.  The paywalled OED has this as its sense 3a:

> 3. a. The hostile force. Originally only as quasi-personified, with agreement in singular; now also as collective with agreement in plural. Also, a hostile ship.

So you could certainly say that the enemy are upon us now to mean the whole mass of them, but you cannot then count them by saying <sup>✽</sup>*five enemy* to mean five **of** the enemy. Therefore you may not then use it with quantifiers; only partitive constructions are then allowed, just as with any other mass noun whether singular or plural.

This is not actually an irregular plural. It’s just something you can do with collective nouns in English, like when the jury are still sequestered in deliberations. That is not irregular.

Comment: I know it's common (and hence eventually correct) usage, but it's always sounded strange to my ear to use it as a plural. Same with jury.  They both just sound more correct as a singular.

Comment: Apparently, 'police' is _quasi-count_, with the count usage '2000 police' now accepted but '6 police' not.